# NSTableview in Dark mode

Tags: xcode, macos

I updated my app for macOS.
Everything is Ok except in dark mode

[image]
[image]

the row text( black color ) disappeared

all other GUI component are display well.

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `Highlight` popup to `Source List`

Answer (score 1):

You've set a custom background color of pure white.  Change it back to the default.